# QR code generation for wifi, geolocation,contact,etc using flutter packages?

Tags: flutter, qr-code

I would like to generate QR codes for wifi, vcard/contact, geolocation,etc but the qr code packages for flutter take string as input. Can anybody tell me how to convert the geolocation,etc to a string format? For example, in the ui for generating Contact qr code, I would give textbox for name, email,phone,etc, But how do I convert all of that into a string input for the Qr code generator package?

Answer (score 1):

For Wifi:

```
WIFI:S:<SSID>;T:<WPA|WEP|>;P:<password>;;
```

For Geolocation:

```
geo:<LAT>,<LNG>
```

Use DD.DDDDD format for latitude and longitue.

For Contact:

```
BEGIN:VCARD
N:Smith;John;
TEL;TYPE=work,VOICE:(111) 555-1212
TEL;TYPE=home,VOICE:(404) 386-1017
TEL;TYPE=fax:(866) 408-1212
EMAIL:smith.j@smithdesigns.com
ORG:Smith Designs LLC
TITLE:Lead Designer
ADR;TYPE=WORK,PREF:;;151 Moore Avenue;Grand Rapids;MI;49503;United States of America
URL:https://www.smithdesigns.com
VERSION:3.0
END:VCARD
```

Comment: Fantastic, excellent. Is there any document where I can refer these formats because there are many other formats like Events,Email, SMS , so it would be great if there was any document for it. Thanks a lot !!!

Comment: No, there's not a centralized documentation or standard as far as I know.

Comment: Somehow this doesn't seem to work. I created a sting such as `'BEGIN:VCARD VERSION:3.0 FN:${_txtFName.value.text} ${_txtLName.value.text} N:${_txtLName.value.text};${_txtFName.value.text} END:VCARD'`, but when I generate the qr code and scan it through my phones camera nothing happens. Any idea?

Comment: qr_flutter library gives flutter: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
BEGIN:VCARD

Please guide

Comment: i need help also. where i can read the document ?